# How to avoid inaccuracy in double numbers C++

Tags: c++, integer, double

I need to print all digets of some double number. I have following code:

```
double number;
    while (number != floor (number)) number = number * 10;
```

But when `number = 0.222`, I have following result `22200000000000004`. How can I avoid this inaccuracy.

P.S. I can use only `double`, so I can't parse this like a `string`.

Comment: You can't, because that's how floating point numbers work. `0.222` has no finite representation in binary, so it has to be rounded, and then you get something like `22200000000000004`. Do you really need to print all the digits, though? Wouldn't it be enough if you did, say, `printf("%.5f", myDouble);` to print 5 decimal places? If that's not good enough, you might want to look into getting a decimal arithmetic libarary.

Comment: You should say why this is a problem for your use-case. If you deal with currencies then you might want to check for a decimal library.

Comment: If this is homework, it's possible that the point of this exercise is that you observe exactly this and start thinking about how that happens.